# Simple map for pipeline in shell script

Tags: shell, dictionary, pipeline

I'm dealing with a pipeline of predominantly shell and Perl files, all of which pass parameters (paths) to the next.  I decided it would be better to use a single file to store all the paths and just call that for every file.  The issue is I am using awk to grab the files at the beginning of each file, and it's turning out to be a lot of repetition.

My question is: I do not know if there is a way to store key-value pairs in a file so shell can natively do something with the key and return the value?  It needs to access an external file, because the pipeline uses many scripts and a map in a specific file would result in parameters being passed everywhere.  Is there some little quirk I do not know of that performs a map function on an external file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a file of env var assignments and source that file as need, ie.

```
$ cat myEnvFile
path1=/x/y/z
path2=/w/xy
path3=/r/s/t
otherOpt1="-x"
```

Inside your script you can source with either `. myEnvFile` or the more versbose version of the same feature `sourc myEnvFile` (assuming bash shell) , i.e.

```
$cat myScript
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/myEnvFile
# main logic below
 ....
# references to defined var
if [[ -d $path2 ]] ; then
     cd $path2
else
     echo "no pa4h2=$path2 found, can't continue" 1>&1
     exit 1
fi
```

Based on how you've described your problem this should work well, and provide a-one-stop-shop for all of your variable settings.

IHTH

Answer (score 3):

In bash, there's [`mapfile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile), but that reads the lines of a file into a numerically-indexed array. To read a whitespace-separated file into an associative array, I would

```
declare -A map
while read key value; do
  map[$key]=$value
done < filename
```

However this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Can you give us an example (in code) of what you're actually doing? When I see long piplines of grep|awk|sed, there's usually a way to simplify. For example, is passing data by parameters better than passing via stdout|stdin?

In other words, I'm questioning your statement "I decided it would be better..."

Comment: I got all excited when I knew what an XY problem was. 
Anyway, I have a huge pipeline of shell and perl files.  The first one takes in about 8 parameters.  It then passes them on to the following script.  Combining this with other variables that hold paths, my ultimate goal is to make the whole pipeline have one file holding all the paths.  Then it references the file whenever it wants a certain path.  The path, right now, is a two column text file and I use awk + regex to find the variable, much like an archaic map structure.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: This may be showing how much of a novice I am, I was "raised" in java.  So I decide things to be better in the mindset of a Java programmer. It may not even be better.